# Ionic keeps taking http get from cache and receives outdated data

Tags: angularjs, ajax, caching, ionic-framework

I have a get request on my server that my app makes a call to, and I had to add an extra property for it to return. I go to the url directly and the new property shows up fine, but when testing on the app in a browser with `ionic serve` the Chrome dev console shows the request comes back without the new property.

I tried using angular `$http.get()` and jQuery `$.ajax()` and both have the same outcome. This happens when testing the app in browser and when testing on an android device, but not when going to the url directly in a browser.

Comment: Have you desactivated the cache on server ?

Comment: @e666 Thanks, I just tried adding the header `res.header('Cache-Control', 'no-cache, private, no-store, must-revalidate, max-stale=0, post-check=0, pre-check=0');` to the response on the server but it has no effect.

Comment: Please see this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/49547/making-sure-a-web-page-is-not-cached-across-all-browsers/2068407#2068407 There is other headers

Comment: @e666 Just tried adding `res.header('Pragma', 'no-cache');` and `res.header('Expires', '0');` but still not working, is that all?